# Python Syntax Non-ASCII character 'xe6' in file (added #-*-coding:utf-8 -*- )

Tags: python

I want to use Python to read the .csv.

At start I search the answer to add the

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding:utf-8 -*-
```

so that  can avoid the problem of encoding, but it is still wrong, giving the syntax error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character 'xe6' in file csv1.py on line2, but no encoding declared:

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-
import csv
with open('wtr1.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print row
```

Comment: Try put a space in the 2nd line after the # sign

Comment: How are you attemping to read the CSV file? The builtin in CSV module only really works well with ASCII - regardless of any other form of encoding...

Comment: Are those really the first two lines of csv1.py? I ask because he error says there is \xe6 in 2nd line.

Comment: @zvone that's the CSV module complaining it can't read the data because of what I mentioned in the above comment. Jonathan - it'd be handy if you posted your actual code and traceback instead of a screenshot of the traceback... Look at how to make a [mcve]

Comment: @ chenchuk I try it and the result is  same.@ Ninja Puppy because i finally want to use the sqlite to connect to the djanogo, and that file is saved the temperature information using arduino.  @zvone whatever i adust the line (movede two first line in to 3,4th,the result is same

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two different errors here. This answer relates to the `with` warning. The other error is the ascii encoding error.

You appear to be using a very old version of python (2.5). The `with` statement is not enabled by default in python 2.5. Instead you have to declare a the top of the file that you wish to use it. Your file should now look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import with_statement

import csv
with open('wtr1.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print row
```

Comment: oh i paste wrong because the warning is from codepad.so u can ignore this part. but what was the wrong about encoding i did?thx!

Comment: @JonathanCheng The code that you've posted does not contain the character that the error reports. Maybe it was lost when pasting your code. Try copying the code you've posted into a new file and seeing if that works.

Comment: finally i success because should type`# - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-` instead of `# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-`.so wierd~and thx reply:))